# Why is one iteration in my loop skipped when I print in a loop using the command prompt?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I wrote a function to loop through the columns of a DataFrame and print various attributes, but I found that when running the function via the terminal in VS Code, it skips one of the iterations. The iteration it skips changes depending on the size of the DataFrame. When I run the same code in an interactive session, it prints everything as expected. It is only when I run the code in the terminal that it behaves strangely. Any idea why?

Here is a very basic version of the code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
def sas_import_csv(df):
    '''Takes a dataframe and prepares a data step to import the csv file to SAS.
    '''
    opening = 'some text'
    closing = 'some more text'
    print(f'{opening}')
    for col in df.columns:
        print(f'{col}')

    for col2 in df.columns:
        print(f'\t{col2}')

    for col3 in df.columns:
        print(f'\t\t{col3}')
    print(closing)

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list("ABCD"))
df['E'] = "some string"
df = df.reset_index()
sas_import_csv(df)
```

Which outputs the below - skipping column A in the first loop.

```
some text
index
B
C
D
E
        index
        A
        B
        C
        D
        E
                index
                A
                B
                C
                D
                E
some more text
```

My original code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
def sas_import_csv(df):
    '''Takes a dataframe and prepares a data step to import the csv file to SAS.
    '''
    value_fmts = [np.float,np.int32,np.int64]
    opening = '''data **infile** %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */ 
infile **filepath** delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;'''
    closing = ''';
if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;'''
    measurer = np.vectorize(len)
    dfLen = measurer(df.values.astype(str)).max(axis=0)
    print(f'{opening}')
    for l,col in zip(dfLen,df.columns):
        if df[col].dtypes in value_fmts: infmt = 'Best32. ;'
        else: infmt = f'${l}. ;'
        print(f'\tinformat {col} {infmt}')
    for l2,col2 in zip(dfLen,df.columns):
        if df[col2].dtypes in value_fmts: fmt = 'Best12. ;'
        else: fmt = f'${l2}. ;'
        print(f'\tformat {col2} {fmt}')
    for col3 in df.columns:
        if df[col3].dtypes in value_fmts: ct = ''
        else: ct = '$'
        print(f'\t\tinput {col3} {ct}')
    print(closing)

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list("ABCD"))
df['E'] = "some string"
sas_import_csv(df)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the script through terminal / command prompt (not on VS Code)? I always get all of the columns (on my IDE and terminal).

Comment: @oda Just tried that and it prints just fine from the command prompt, also if I call the script from the VS Terminal then it prints fine. But when if I call the function while in python in the VS terminal it has the issue

Comment: That is very strange.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have understood it correctly. I've tried it out and it works smoothly on both PyCharm, Windows, and VSCode terminal. If you're getting the wrong output when importing and using the function from another script, I guess the problem is in the data frame variable.

Comment: @oda just tried it on another computer and it works fine also. Seems to be an issue only when submitting it line by line in the VS Code Terminal on this machine.

Comment: Very very strange. The second and third loops are identical to the first yet the first is skipping the `A`. You are running this in VS Code Terminal by simply entering `sas_import_csv(df)` yes?

Comment: I've been running it by selecting the block of text and pressing `shift+enter`. Or by entering each piece of the code line by line in the terminal. If I run the script by calling the filename from the terminal it is fine. I have the same issue in PyCharm if I try to call sas_import_csv(df) from the terminal.

Comment: I just added the code I started with before dumbing it down. When I run the original chunk of code, it skips column `D` in the first loop. I'm just confused why it is happening, but I guess the answer is to avoid it all together by calling it as a script or running it interactively